# Google Static Maps don't work with Google APIs Console generated key

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using the [Google Static Maps API](https://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Since Google introduced the [following restriction for maps usage](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/11/understanding-how-maps-api-usage-limits.html)  I added an key parameter to my image urls.
The key was generated here: https://code.google.com/apis/console

After I added the key parameter the map image requests fail with a 403 status code and the following message: *This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/.*

If I remove the key the requests return a 200-OK status code.

The reports in the Google APIs Console are showing ~100K requests so far, even though the clients don't see any Maps images.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and realized that I had turned on the Maps v3 service (assuming that covered static maps) but NOT the static maps service which appears further down the alphabetized list.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Static Maps don't require a key anymore, they are also not available inside the console. So I guess you created a key for a maps-javascript-API and use this key for a static map, what will result in the error.

There is no need for a key anymore in static maps, because the limits now are bound to the user and not to the provider.

Comment: I'm now with the same issue with Static maps API. Using my API key, i get an empty image with an exclamation icon.If I delete the key parameter, i get this error: The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: When I go there and login my account, I get: This project does not have a billing account. You will need to add billing information for this project to continue to use Google Maps Platform. The first $200 of monthly usage is free.